# DVD not displaying full picture

Tags: transcoding, mpeg, dvd, aspect, encore

I have created a DVD from video files, originally FLV 1280x720p files.

Although I followed the support literature and help guides, **approx 10 pixels are missing vertically and approx 20 horizontally from all the DVD content(I have tried 2 players/TVs with same result)**(like a slightly zoomed-in effect). 
In Encore and WMP, it plays perfectly fine.

**This is the transcoded file:**
`General
Name                                     : ZZ Top.m2v
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2
File size                                : 2.02 GiB
Duration                                 : 57 min 12 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 053 kb/s

Video
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Main@Main
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default
Format settings, GOP                     : M=3, N=12
Duration                                 : 57 min 12 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 5 053 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 7 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Standard                                 : PAL
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel x Frame)                     : 0.487
Time code of first frame                 : 00:00:00:00
GOP, Open/Closed                         : Closed
Stream size                              : 2.02 GiB (100%)`
**This is a VOB off the DVD;**

`General
Complete name                            : G:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_02_1.VOB
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 1 024 MiB
Duration                                 : 26 min 51 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 329 kb/s

Video
ID                                       : 224 (0xE0)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Main@Main
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default
Format settings, GOP                     : M=3, N=12
Duration                                 : 26 min 51 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 5 031 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 7 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Standard                                 : PAL
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel x Frame)                     : 0.485
Time code of first frame                 : 00:00:00:00
Time code source                         : Group of pictures header
GOP, Open/Closed                         : Closed
Stream size                              : 967 MiB (94%)`

**More info:**
The first DVD player(Panasonic) is quite versatile with regards to settings. I use the [component(R/G/B)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_video) output(576p) and the HDTV(Samsung) recognizes it as 720 x 576p. I have tried different aspect ratio settings on both TVs and DVD players and the best/closest settings are:
DVD Players: 16:9 (1.0x zoom)
TVs: 16:9

**NOTES:**

- Curiously, I have two **video-loop-buttons** "(%)" in the Main Menu, and in those, the same slightly zoomed-in effect occurs on the video, even while previewing in Encore, but I think that is because I used a 1280x720 thumbnail of the original HD video. Just thought I'd mention that.
- I used "Scale to Fill" during rendering in AME, because of black lines on the sides.
- This issue is very recognizable due to the logo in the top left of the screen being 1/3rd missing.
- I am in the UK(i.e. PAL). But I wonder if a NTSC render would resolve this? Is this the kind of effect using wrong TV standards would cause? Or is it an [overscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan) issue?

Comment: The horizontal crop sounds like overscan - PAL active area is ~703 pixels out of 120, so 2.4% which is 25 pixels out of 1024 px your content effectively is. As for the vertical, if your players are zooming in to preserve ratio, that could be it. Render to 702 or 703x576 and pad to 720 with black.

Comment: Wow - ZZ Top, overscan, I'm having a flashback! It indeed sounds like an overscan issue Have you tried playing it on a computer?

Comment: @stib Haha, yeah. The menu and videos are perfect when the DVD is played on computer(WMP). On the two DVD players, even the menu is "zoomed in" slightly. I don't think it is stretched or anything, just slightly zoomed in both dimensions possibly equally.

Comment: @Mulvya Does overscan not 'crop' vertically then?  The problem is, how can I render the menu at 702 in Encore? When rendering the *videos* in AME, I could have left the 8 pixel side bars instead of 'Scalling to fill', but I don't know how to do it for the menu. I'm currently creating a test DVD with test display videos and menus rendered differently to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hold the flip-phone... I just selected 4:3LB on the DVD player, and I can now see the top & bottom of the video and menu, but there are also black bars above and below, so the image is squashed because the sides are still missing(unchanged). I don't like this game.

Comment: silly question but when you built the DVD menu and all did you turn on the TITLE safe area so anything inside this area will guarantee the menus and anything else will be shown. or am I just under thinking this ?

Comment: @AdamMannPro (I think) you're spot on there. I didn't work with the safe-areas in mind. I have never created a video where these bounds really mattered. I am still troubled by the fact that pixels are purposely removed from a SD format like DVD.

Comment: @Mulvya The video def looks better @ 702, so thanks for that. One more question; Do people who convert to DVD format adjust the video to fit it in the action safe area? Or do they just accept that they have lost some of the picture?

Comment: I haven't made a DVD in a long time but as I remember, I didn't adjust the video, because the footage and graphics are shot/made with the action/title safe area in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to work within the title safe areas when burning to DVD as depending on what the final player will be, there might be overscan which will/can crop anything out that is not within this field. as for the pixel things, I'm not to sure.

Comment: Yes, but I was really looking for a solution to the problrem. But I don't think there is one. Do people who convert to DVD format adjust the video to fit it in the action safe area? Or do they just accept that they have lost some of the picture?

Comment: I do make DVD's all the time, I do all my editing in my NLE (FCPX) then I export using Compressor and open up DVD Studio Pro to build my DVD menu and content. when building the DVD it will always put all my content into view but turning the title safe on it will show me what is going to show on hte screen and what might be potentially cut out depending on the viewers TV (all makes and models show different amounts) some will over scan and some will compensate, I know I have  all Samsung TV's (1 overscans a lot, 1 is just a little bit and the other is kind of mid range)

Comment: Ah, so it is the TV that removes the edges, not the DVD player. **That confuses me**, because it was originally added to resolve issues with CRT displays, so I can't see why LCD TVs still overscan. I have samsung too. I roughly measured the overscan to around 4%.

Comment: its mainly down to the amount of "Screen" behind the bezel around the edges, CRT's had quite a to hold them in, LCD's/LED's all have weird and wonderful bezels which hold the screen bit in.

Comment: I disagree with that last comment, because CRT TVs, as I remember, didn't have trim on the screen. The phosphor 'pixel' things ended at a black strip (inside the screen), so they didn't even reach the bezel. That's early to mid 90's TVs I'm talking about. and newer LCD/LEDs(I have LED) are more precise, the pixels ending at the bezel. So I don't think the display (pixels) ever passed the bezel. This is more of a technical thing.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an exact answer or solution here, or on any other forums.

The general answer is basically:
***"It's most probably overscan, which isn't a universal, predictable measurement, so you are going to lose some of your picture and there's nothing you can do about it"***

This doesn't really make sense to me, removing varying amounts of pixels from an already limited range. Plus, I can only find literature on *why* it was originally implemented, so I'm not even sure if it's the TV or the DVD player removing these pixels. I created a test DVD, so I'm at least sure of the bounds for *my* TV/DVD player(which is just outside the action-safe 5%(so ~4%)). But this doesn't help me with the resolution which is obviously lowered due to this process.

Comment: not quite correct - as Adam pointed out, if you turn title safe on, you will not lose anything from overscan.

Comment: @DrMayhem No, you still lose the same amount, the title safe margins Adam is referring to are just guides. It makes no difference to the boarders of the final display.